# Recode many factors using many different codings in R using fct_recode (ideally)

Tags: r

I have many datasets, from one project. These contain hundreds of variables (each). A proportion of these are coded, in many different ways, and they come to me as character variables, and a separate file of what the codes mean, for the coded variables only, arranged by variable name. Most have less than 10 allowed values, but some are longer.

The data look like this sample :-

```
DataTEST <- tibble(V1 = sample(c(1,2,3,NA), 50, replace = TRUE),
             V2 = sample(c('a', 'b', 'c',NA), 50, replace = TRUE),
             V3 = sample(c(20,30,40,NA), 50, replace = TRUE))

Codes <- tibble(Name = c('V1','V2','V3'),
                Code = c('Never = 1, Sometimes = 2, Always = 3',
                         'Apple = a, Banana = c, Clementine = c',
                         'At_home = 20, At_work = 30, Other = 40'))
```

There are some variables with the same coding in the real data, but what I have is one row of codes, as a string, for every variable name.

My basic idea was to use fct_recode. So, first I wanted to make the factors

```
str(DataTEST)
DataTEST <- DataTEST %>% mutate(across(Codes$Name, ~as.factor(.x)))
str(DataTEST)
```

This works very nicely. So I tried this :-

```
DataTEST %>% mutate(across(Codes$Name,
                      ~fct_recode(.x, Codes$Coding[match(.x, Codes$Name)])))
```

This does not work, and the error message is

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `across(Codes$Name, ~fct_recode(.x, Codes$Coding[match(.x, Codes$Name)]))`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Can't compute column `V1`.
Caused by error in `fct_recode()`:
! Each element of `...` must be a named string.
ℹ Problems with 1 argument: 1
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I've tried various things, including changing the Coding to be the string (for example)

```
"V1 = C(Never = 1, Sometimes = 2, Always = 3)"
```

None seem to work.

It may be as simple as figuring out how to name the string, or it may involve presenting the text string from the dataframe ("V1 = c(Never ...)" to R for evaluation...

Advice would be very welcome!